# How to change the behavior of the DataGridView when clicking a column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When I click a column of the DataGridView control, the control sorts all the data according to the column.

Is it possible to disable this function? (Actually I want to select the whole column as in Excel or Word tables.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable sorting in the grid, all you need to is to set the `SortMode` property of each column to `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable`, like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

As for the full column selection, that functionality is not present. Making it work will need quite some work (if it is possible at all, which I doubt is anyways!).